# How do I merge a zoo object but using a lag and a varying column?

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

If I have a zoo object with multiple series, as so (call it zoo1):

```
          'SPY'    'XLE'   'XLF'   'XLY'
1/1/2000   .002    .015    .005    .021 
2/1/2000   .051    .007    .070    .011
3/1/2000   .007    .102    .143    .095
```

and another (zoo2) that represents the max value by row of the above (but excludes column 'SPY'):

```
1/1/2000    'XLY'
2/1/2000    'XLF'
3/1/2000    'XLF'
```

How do I get a zoo object that is the pairing of the 'SPY' value from zoo1, as well as the value from zoo1, column indexed by the column referenced in zoo2, but lagged (-1) month. A general description of the task would be that I want to pair the monthly number for SPY with the number for the same month of the symbol that performed best in the prior month. By visual example:

```
           'SPY'   Current_Perf_Of_Prior_Month_Best_Performer
2/1/2000   .051    .011
3/1/2000   .007    .143
```

I've tried indexing, read many articles on joins, and even downloaded and attempted to use package sqldf, along with a custom function. Time to punt. Seems like it should be *relatively* straightforward. Any takers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question, because your question is a round-about way to achieve the same result. You don't need the `zoo2` object.

```
# reproducible data
Lines <- 
"'Date'     'SPY'    'XLE'   'XLF'   'XLY'
1/1/2000   .002    .015    .005    .021 
2/1/2000   .051    .007    .070    .011
3/1/2000   .007    .102    .143    .095"
zoo1 <- read.zoo(text=Lines, header=TRUE, format="%m/%d/%Y")

# Get return at (t) for best performer at (t-1)
x <- rollapplyr(zoo1, 2, function(x) x[2,which.max(x[1,])], by.column=FALSE)
# merge with original data
merge(zoo1, x)
#              SPY   XLE   XLF   XLY curBestLag
# 2000-01-01 0.002 0.015 0.005 0.021         NA
# 2000-02-01 0.051 0.007 0.070 0.011      0.011
# 2000-03-01 0.007 0.102 0.143 0.095      0.143
```

Comment: @StatsViaCsh: no it does not. Run the code and look at the output. It contains `zoo1` with an additional column `retmaxlag` that contains the `Current_Perf_Of_Prior_Month_Best_Performer` you wanted.

Comment: So it is! What I need though, for the additional column, is the value for the current month of the symbol that was the max in the prior month. My use of lag was to get the symbol that was the best performer in the prior month. As it is now, it just returns the performance of that symbol for the prior month.

Comment: @StatsViaCsh: Not sure how I missed that... see my updated answer.